# How to put keys of dictionary in first row of csv rather than first column?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, transpose

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
list1 = ['a1', 'b3', 'c4', 'd2', 'h0', 'k1', 'p2', 'o3']
list2 = ['1', '2', '25', '23', '4', '5', '6', '210', '8', '02', '92', '320']


abc = dict(zip(keys[:4], [list1,list2]))

with open('myfilecsvs.csv', 'wb') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in abc.items()]
```

I am getting all keys in 1st column with this and values in other column respectively.

What I am trying to achieve is all keys in first row i-e each key in specific column of first row and then their values below. Something like transpose

I willbe much grateful for your assist on this

Comment: Please add an expected output for the sample input you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `zip_longest` to do this.

`",".join(abc.keys())` will return first row (the keys) like `key1,key2`,and then use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)(Python2.x use `izip_longest`) to aggregate elements.And use the same way append `,` and `\n` to the string.

**zip_longest**

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('myfilecsvs.csv', 'w') as f:
   f.write("\n".join([",".join(abc.keys()),*(",".join(i) for i in zip_longest(*abc.values(),fillvalue=''))]))
```

Output:

```
key1,key2
a1,1
b3,2
...
,02
,92
,320
```